# Oracle scaling while executing dynamically generated SQL queries

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a use case where in the user some input data and then in backend  SQL queries are generated  depending on inputs.

User enters multiple filter criteria which gets translated into a new 
clause.Eg `(someCol1='valA' and someColB ='valP' )`

User can enter as many as 10000 clauses and the DB takes a hit.

Eg

```
select * from table where  (
(someCol1='valA' and someColB ='valP' ) OR
(someCol1='valB' and someColB ='valQ' ) OR
(someCol1='valC' and someColB ='valR' ) OR
(someCol1='valD' and someColB ='valS' ) OR
....
(someCol1='valE' and someColB ='valT' ) OR
)
```

The problem is the execution time increases when the number of clauses are  large (around 1000).Response time can as large as 5 min but it the job  should never fail.

I am using an Oracle DB, and there are no DB joins. All queries run against single DB.

Comment: Your question lacks some important details. What is the UI application? Do you have control on how SQL is generated? And the most important: what is your concern? Are your doubts about performance issues when query is run against database or about that query text exceeds maximum statement length limit?

Comment: Not helpful,but this is bad design: letting the user generate huge OR queries.

Comment: @YaroslavShabalin There is some kind of 2D table and depending on which cell users select a clause is geenrated.Now if the  user sleect N cells then N clauses will be generated.The concers in scaling.IF uers selects 1000 cell the queries run for a very long time and sometime fails

Comment: How large is the table being queried? How much of that would be returned if there were 10k `or` clauses? (Sounds like a horrible problem to have, sorry.)

Comment: @Mat Tables have round missions (100 million) of records :( . and query filters around 1lacks records

Comment: The only way I can think of of making this manageable would be to split into multiple `select`s. Is that something you could do?

Comment: You could try to create a bitmap index on `(someCol1, someColB') or even one bitmap index on `someCol1` and one on `someColB`. **But**: bitmap indexes don't work very well in environments where you do a lot of DML against the table. If the index(es) help, you will need to decide if you can live with the disadvantages. Btw: you are not joining "databases", you are joining *tables*. And in your query there is only a single *table*, not a single "DB".

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend using a temporary table with filters.

If You have small number of filters (SomeCol1, SomeColB,..) then filters can be stored in "flat" table:

```
FLTRS_TMP ( filter_seq_id, SomeCol1_id, SomeColB_id, ... )
```

Then You can join the table on specific columns:

```
select * from FACT_TABLE F, FLTRS_TMP FT
 where nvl(F.SomeCol1_id,'!null!') = nvl(FT.SomeCol1_id,'!null!')
   and nvl(F.SomeColB_id,'!null!') = nvl(FT.SomeColB_id,'!null!')
   and ...
```

But if number of filters is relatively too big, You can consider placing filters in attribute-like (unpivoted) table:

```
FLTRS_TMP ( filter_seq_id, filter_family_seq_id, column_name, column_value )
```

`filter_family_seq_id` is used to group `AND` conditions (separate different `OR` conditions). If different operators are to be used You can add `operator_id` column. In the end FLTRS_TMP table is most likely to be pivoted before join with FACT_TABLE.